# Class cannot be static in Apex

Tags: apex, compile

This might be a duplicate question but I couldn't find any answers. According to the documentation:

> In Apex, you can have static methods, variables, and initialization
>   code. However, Apex classes can’t be static.

I'm wondering why is that? My guess it has something to do with the Apex compiler, when sending uncompiled code to the server and it cannot access static classes ?

Hopefully someone might have an answer based on evidence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Taking Java as an example, the [static keyword can only be applied to a nested class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html). There it is used to distinguish between nested classes that can automatically reference the fields of the outer class (no `static` keyword) and nested classes that cannot automatically reference the fields of the outer class (`static` keyword).

In Apex, there is no variation possible: all nested classed behave like Java `static` nested classes. So the keyword is redundant when applied to classes in Apex and so not available.